# trying to run an led off of 4 triple A batteries

Tags: led

I am trying to run an led off four triple A batteries

It's wired to a button to indicate on.

Is this possible and if so what is the right method

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: what LED are you talking about?

Comment: It's possible and there's loads of examples to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If the batteries are in series it should be possible.

You'll need to calculate a current limit resistor in accordance with Ohm's law.

Formally for that, you need to know the forward voltage of the LED, and the rated current.  But if we neglect the forward voltage entirely things will just come out on the dim side, and if we guess for say 10 milliamps you are probably OK with most LEDS.

So applying ohms law, 4 * 1.5 = 6 volts divided by .010 amperes yields 600 ohms.

Resistors come in a series of well spaced values that superficially look funny but actually do a very good job of providing choices.  The closest choice in the most common series would be 680 ohms, but 470 ohms is also available in that series and would not be unreasonable as a starting point either.  You may also find 560.

So, put your 4 batteries cells in series, then from the positive lead of the most positive battery cell connect to your resistor, then from the other side of that to the long lead of your LED, and from the short lead of your LED back to the negative side of the most negative battery.

If you knew the forward voltage of the LED, you'd first subtract that from the battery voltage before calculating; if you had the current rating of the LED, you could start there instead - but "junkbox" parts exist, most people won't hesitate to reach for an indicator LED for a one-off project just because they don't have its specifics.

Speaking more generally, you could also use three cells with a smaller resistor.  If the LED is a red one, even two might work, but for blue or (modern) green LEDs, that might not be enough voltage to exceed the LED forward voltage and produce much light.  When the battery voltage is that close to the LED forward voltage, current regulation with a resistor ceases to work anyway, as the battery voltage would vary too much during the course of its discharge.  In that kind of case, say an high power efficient LED flashlight, more active current-regulating driver circuits are needed.

Comment: ok youve just thrown me right of with an amazing response. problem is i dont get electrics or the words used. there is no info on my led as it be impossible to put any on, its tiny.

Comment: If you knew what it was when purchased you could get the data sheet.  But one found in a drawer of random parts won't have one, no.  All of the forward voltage and current explanation is for more formal engineering.  To simply make a common indicator LED light up follow the paragraphs about possible resistors and how it all hooks up.  Don't be tempted to skip the resistor or the LED will probably give one quick flash then die...

Comment: this is all to confusing. you all talk like pros and im deaf. so i dont understand any of this. pictures is what i need to see. an led to resistor to batteries, all labelled correctly with names and what they are. schematics is not for me ever. gave me a headache trying to understand that to complicated and messy. so what im asking is can you basically give me the kids version, pictures and simple info. sorry for being thick but this is beyond me. thanks for your patience

Comment: There are plenty of places you can find picture tutorials on the Internet with a search engine.  But it's not really what this particular site is for.  Different places for different approaches for different needs